# CSS slider width issue at max-width: 980px

Tags: html, css, resize, prestashop, prestashop-1.5

I think i have some css problem.

At fullpage width the slider width is ok.

But at @media screen and (max-width: 980px) the slider is missing on each side.

Any one got a clue?

URL: removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In media query `@media screen and (max-width: 980px)` you are giving `width:535px` to `bx-wrapper`. Remove that line & it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing line 79 in your responsive.css

To 600px width.

```
.bx-wrapper{width:600px !important; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;}
```

Answer (score 0):

The sides are missing because there is a `width:535px !important` set for the `.bx-wrapper` in the media query for `@media screen and (max-width: 980px)`. Try overriding this in your style sheet with this

```
.bx-wrapper{
  width:100% !important;
}
```

Add this in your style-sheet to the media query `@media screen and (max-width: 980px)`